video tag html does not work in Chrome when source is a http stream whit vlc
Currently I have VLC media player streaming a video file out through http on port 8080.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</head>
<body>
<h1>video</h1>            
<video src="http://localhost:8080" autoplay width="340" height="280"></video>
</body>
</html>

I can see the stream that VLC is sending out playing in the browser Firefox.
This code works with Firefox.this code does not work in Chrome.
Does chrome support http streams for ?
video tag  html does not work in Chrome when source is a http stream whit vlc
